# does i need to upload my website that uses Facebook API?

Tags: facebook

as mentioned in the title , does i need to upload the website to test the integration of Facebook graph API, or can i use it locally ??

Answer (score 0):

You can test your facebook app locally.  If you're using iframe, it should be fairly straight forward because I believe you can even use http://localhost.  If you're using FBML, then facebook needs to invoke your web server, so you'll need to expose your local web server externally.  This means that you'll need to open a port through your firewall and expose your local web server through your external IP address.  This is the IP address that you need to register with Facebook though your application settings.